# How to back up RAID (PERC) configurations?

Tags: linux, backup, raid, dell, dell-perc

At my site we have several RAID storage servers, mostly using Dell PERC cards. I was wondering if anyone is aware of a way to take automated backups of the PERC configuration? The reason I ask is that Dell support has in several cases told us to wipe out our PERC configuration, in order to have the PERC card reset using the configs stored on disk. However, in at least two cases, this has failed for us, leading to some very lengthy restore processes. We're running Linux on all of our servers, mostly RHEL/CentOS, but also a few Ubuntu machines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds unique to the PERC cards, so I would ask Dell. It's their hardware, they should provide a solution - or at least point you in the right direction.

If they balk at helping, you can just tell them that the next time you're looking for a solution you'll be sure to look elsewhere, and if you suffer another loss, you just might complain on the various internet boards...

RT